# Changing the Lengths of Words in a String - Java

Tags: java, string

I am currently writing a game in Java, where words in a string will have to be all changed to equal 5 characters a word.

eg. I am writing in Java
    Iamwr iting inJav a

I wonder if anyone knows how I would do this?

Comment: SO is not a "write code from me" site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First remove spaces between words. 
Then split that resulting `String` to length with `5`.
Add a space after every `5` character.